# Why are my fittings leaking?

Tags: plumbing, leak, npt, brass-fitting

I am installing a new Hansgrohe shower. It came with this part https://www.hansgrohe-usa.com/articledetail-showerpipe-basic-set-16181181 that I decided to connect to this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002UQ1ZBA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002UQ1ZBA) - They are both 1/2 NPT and I am using teflon tape.

I originally tighten the fitting by hand and then turned back on the water, and it started to leak slightly around the teflon tape [see picture]. I then tightened it with a pair of pliers as hard as I could but water continues to drip, one drop per 30 sec. What am I doing wrong? I am worried to break the fitting if I continue to tighten with a tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using pipe dope (paste, typically in a small tube for homeowner-sized quantities) as it's not as fussy as tape, particularly with today's often poorly machined threads (lead-free makes cutting nice threads in brass much more difficult.)

Comment: thank you @Ecnerwal I resolved it because  you put me on the right path: I think I did not use enough teflon tape, and it might have not been tight enough. I have redone it tighter with more tape, and the leak is gone. Feel free to answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I think you have not tightened it enough. The diagram shows the small threading gap at 1/2 inch in from the end; from your photo about 1/4 inch of the threading is still visible, meaning only about 1/4 inch is screwed in. For a good seal with 1/2 inch NPT, about 7/16 inch is expected to be screwed in.